# Create git branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to create a new branch of my git repository directly on github.com via website, but when I click on branches list, there is no option to create one

Image:

[image: Snapshot]

How can i create one? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, I was very distracted when looking for the answrer online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start typing the name of the branch you want to create and it will let you open it.

As seen here: [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way also:

1. Clone repository on your local machine
2. Create a new branch out of it using the command

   git checkout -b `<your_new_branch_name>`
3. Push your local branch to remote

   git push -u origin `<your_branch_name>`

Comment: OP asked "create a new branch of my git repository **directly on github.com via website**", this does not answer that.

Comment: I want to do it inside the website, without cloning my repo on my desktop